# How to replace a certain character in a string with another character in c#?

Tags: c#, replace

I have a string

```
String s = "S-et6-Rtttdd+4554/dsdsrlsd="
```

I am using `Replace` to replace it with another character

```
String g = s.Replace("/","%2f");
String r = g.Replace("=","%3b");
String f = r.Replace("/+","%2b");
```

Output ->

```
S-et6-Rtttdd+4554%2fdsdsrlsd%3d
```

Desired Output ->

```
S-et6-Rtttdd+4554%2fdsdsrlsd%3d
```

I am not understanding how to replace the "+" sign with the desired output. This is meant for HTTP encoding.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - there is a method for that already: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You output and your desired output are the same. I dint see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to escape anything. This should work just fine

```
String f = r.Replace("+","%2b");
```

Proof:

```
void Main()
{
    String s = "S-et6-Rtttdd+4554/dsdsrlsd=";
    String g = s.Replace("/","%2f");
    String r = g.Replace("=","%3b");
    String f = r.Replace("+","%2b");
    Console.WriteLine (f);
}
```

Outputs

> S-et6-Rtttdd%2b4554%2fdsdsrlsd%3b

Comment: Maybe you had to clean up the project or you thought you did it but actually didn't or you did it but overlooked it, or.. There's an infinite amount of explanations to why something may have been different in the past.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel my string replaces the character "+" to space character " ". I use your code String f = r.Replace("+","%2b");